# Unnecessary escape character: \[ no-useless-escape

Tags: javascript, regex, ecmascript-6, jslint

JSlint is complaining about unnecessary escape characters but I can't seem to figure out why.  Here are my regex's, any ideas?

Unnecessary escape character: [  no-useless-escape

```
const _emailRegex = /^(([^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()\[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;

const _phoneRegex = /^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/;
```

Comment: The opening square bracket `[` does not need to be escaped within a character set.

Comment: The `/^\(?(\d{3})\)?[- ]?(\d{3})[- ]?(\d{4})$/` works OK. Right?

Comment: thanks, that worked

Answer (score 5):

like @gyre said, needed to remove a couple ['s.

```
const _emailRegex = /^(([^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+(\.[^<>()[\]\\.,;:\s@"]+)*)|(".+"))@((\[[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}\.[0-9]{1,3}])|(([a-zA-Z\-0-9]+\.)+[a-zA-Z]{2,}))$/;
```

Comment: If you test it with `/u` modifier in Chrome, it throws *Lone quantifier brackets at <anonymous>:1:1*. Try [this one](https://regex101.com/r/odWxJP/1).

Answer (score 2):

In javascript when creating a regular expression, **the characters placed inside a character class**, that means inside [...], **do not need to be escaped** except the following characters: the closing bracket ], the backslash \, the caret ^, and the hyphen -

The only reason for that eslint warning to appear is just to improve readability, so your regulars expressions should still be working fine.